# Active version of "occur to"

Tags: single-word-requests, active-voice

> They don't know what they don't know and never *occur that there's more to know.

What is a better fit for "occur," here used actively, here? Passively, it is:

> They don't know what they don't know and *it never occurs to them* that there's more to know.

Comment: "Realize", maybe?

Comment: An idea occurred to me/ struck me. It is somewhere near?

Comment: _It never occurs to me_ is not Passive. Passive requires a form of _be_ followed by a past participle. Neither one of them is here.

Comment: That's not the passive voice; you have a dummy *it*, which is what we tend to use when we have a long *that*-clause as a subject. You can replace the dummy *it * the long *that*-clause: *They don't know what they don't know, and that there's more to know never occurs to them.* Or just leave it off; you've just said the same thing twice.